# How to make the Plot3D with colors?

Tags: graphics

I would like the make a 3D Graph with Plot3D like the following picture shows:[image]

So I write in the notebook of Mathematica the following :

**Plot3D[x^2 + y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]**

But which option of Plot3D shall I write to get the nice coloring I see in the picture?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ColorFunction->"WatermelonColors"`